# Running an application (.exe) in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, exe, launch

When I download an application on chrome, clicking the finished download causes the app to start through chrome. 
I was wondering if there was any manner I could do this on a general basis.

Now if you run chrome with `chrome.exe --show-app-list` it runs the chrome app launcher. If there was a way to launch applications in a similar manner, that would be exceptional.
I've already tried entering the file path of the program in the URL bar, but that simply copies the application to my downloads folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Mona

Comment: What do you mean, "causes the app to start through chrome"? Chrome just launches the exe. Why don't you just launch your executable directly?

Comment: @Blorgbeard When I launched the exe "through chrome", I was logged in as a restricted user, in which group policy block's the exe. When I ran the exe through chrome- I wasnt prompted or blocked.